# How do i put together two pandas DataFrames only at timestamp data matching eachother?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames looking similar to the one below.They though have different lengths and data values.

I want to **put together the two dataframes at the timestamps that match each other from both the dataframes**.

Such that I end up with ideally one dataframe containing all the data from both dataframes at matching timestamps or two dataframes with similar lengths for the matching timestamps would also be okay.

How can I do this most efficiently :)?

> 1. Location UnitNameREF         TimestampREF  PowerREF WindspeedREF
> 2. 0   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 00:00:00  7.563642     3.957911
> 3. 2   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 00:20:00  60.73445     4.241572
> 4. 3   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 00:30:00  63.15441      4.24109
> 5. 4   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 00:40:00   59.0928      4.38905
> 6. 5   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 00:50:00  69.26197     4.374599
> 7. 6   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 01:00:00  101.0624     5.343887
> 8. 7   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 01:10:00  122.7937     5.183885
> 9. 8   Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 01:20:00  86.57111     5.046734
> 10. 10  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 01:40:00  16.74043     3.024428
> 11. 11  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 01:50:00  12.58701     2.931352
> 12. 12  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 02:00:00 -1.029754     3.116549
> 13. 13  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 02:10:00  13.35998     3.448056
> 14. 14  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 02:20:00  17.42461     2.943588
> 15. 19  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 02:50:00 -11.01966     3.554834
> 16. 20  Bull Creek         F10  2014-11-01 03:00:00  -4.38301     4.279259

```
     fileREF = 'FilterDataREF.xlsx'

     dataREF = pd.read_excel(fileREF, sheetname='Sheet1')
```

Comment: If datetimes are unique in each DataFrame, simpliest is `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='TimestampREF')`, but then it is dupe.

Comment: Well the datetime format is the same for the two dataframes put the name of the timestamp column is not

Comment: Then use `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='TimestampREF', right_on='another_col_in_df2')`